# Way to combine substrings in dictionary keys

Tags: python, string, dictionary, substring

Is there a fast way to truncate the whitespaces in dictionary keys while retaining the dictionary values? Maybe an enumerate or a dictionary comprehensive method.

I am able to do it with `.replace(" ", "")` but it created a new list with only the keys and not the values.

Example:

```
cities = {
    "Las Vegas": [36.1215, -115.1739],
    "Los Angeles": [34.0500, -118.2500],
    "Salt Lake City": [40.7500, -111.8833]
}
```

to

```
citiesTruncated = {
    "LasVegas": [36.1215, -115.1739],
    "LosAngeles": [34.0500, -118.2500],
    "SaltLakeCity": [40.7500, -111.8833]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dict-comprehension works:

```
citiesTruncated = {key.replace(" ", ""): value for key, value in cities.items()}
```

Note that if you use python2 you should replace the `.items()` by `.iteritems()` to avoid creating an intermediate list.

Comment: Lol, same answer, almost same time!

Comment: I was about to write the same too :D

Comment: Well, this is an example of the python zen: there should only be one preferred way of solving things. I like it!

Comment: Thanks all! Very helpful

Answer (score 4):

Pretty straightforward with a loop or comprehension:

```
citiesTruncated = {key.replace(' ', ''):value for key,value in cities.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain identity of your `dict` there's no such easy way (as `dict` doesn't support slicing). So what you're required to do is something like:

```
for key in cities:
    new_key = key.replace(' ', '')
    if new_key == key:
        continue
    cities[new_key] = d[key]
    del cities[key]
```

Otherwise if you don't require or even don't want to retain identity (`truncatedCities` is a newly created `dict` and not the same as `cities`) you could of course use comprehension:

```
citiesTruncated = {key.replace(" ", ""): value for key, value in cities.items()}
```

Not that in the second solution that even though you end up with a new `dict` the values are still the same (not only equal) - this means that appending something to `cities["Las Vegas"]` will append to `citiesTruncated["LasVegas"]` since they are the same.